# TreeNode not selected after leaving textbox with messagebox, C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a WindowsForm with a treeview and a textbox. When the textbox looses focus a messagebox is shown to ask if the text in the textbox is to be saved. No problem there.
But I want the focus to then be on the treeview and the node that was clicked.
I can get the treeview selected, but not the node.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have so far

Comment: I'm leaving this functionality so this problem can be droped.

Comment: To see a selection either set the focus onthe control or set hideSelection=false!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call

```
myTreeView.Select();
```

to make sure that the node will be selected.

Full example:

```
// Add some example nodes
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Node 1");
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Node 2");
treeView1.Nodes.Add("Node 3");

// Change selection
treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[1];

// Neccessary to highlight the selected node:
treeView1.Select();
```